# A multi user react app not updating state in all tabs when a new user joins(opens a new tab)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have a multi user socket.io React app, where I'm storing the user info in an array on server side. The app does not show all the users logged in all tabs i.e. the array doesn't update in all tabs when a new user logs in/joins.

Server side:

```
let onlineUsers = [];

const addNewUser = (username, socketId) => {
  !onlineUsers.some((user) => user.username === username) &&
  onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  onlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};


io.on('connection', socket => {

  socket.on("newUser", (username) => {
      addNewUser(username, socket.id);
      socket.emit("onlineUsers", onlineUsers);
      socket.emit('yourID', socket.id);
      console.log(onlineUsers);
   });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    removeUser(socket.id);
  });

}
```

Client Side:

```
const [allusers, setAllusers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  socket.current.emit('newUser', user);

  socket.current.on("onlineUsers", onlineUsers => {
     setAllusers(onlineUsers);
  })


  socket.current.on("yourID", (id) => {
    setYourID(id);
  })
}, []);

 return (
  <Row>
    {allusers.map(key => {

      if (key.socketId === yourID) {
        return null
      }

      return (
        <button 
          key={key.socketId} 
          className='knock-btn' 
          onClick={() => callPeer(key.socketId)}
        >
         {key.username}
        </button>
      );
    })}
 </Row>
```

Comment: Have you proved yet that allusers is actually being updated?

Comment: Hi! yes I have. It's updated in each new tab but doesn't in the original one if that make sense? So for tab 1 its 1 user, for tab 2 it shows 2 users and so on...but doesn't automatically update tab 1 when 2 or more users join in.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!! It was a socket issue rather than react. was emitting only 1 socket from server once updated.
so instead of 'socket.emit' used 'io.sockets.emit' and that resolved the issue

Comment: The first thing to do if you think react is not updating is to log the state. Then you will see that the state isn't actually being updated.